# Using FFMPEG to find the coordinates of the rightmost filled pixel in a png with transparency

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, image-editing, watermark

Let's say I want to watermark several photos like this.

[A sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJp2p.jpg)

I will have several pictures with different bottom-most-right-most non-transparent pixel. The marked coordinate is what I need to calculate for the script.

[The marked coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZJRY.jpg)

My current script is:

```
for %j in (*.webp) do ffmpeg -i "%j" -i "C:\pad\watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5" -c:v libwebp "%~nj_watermarked.webp"
```

[Which results in this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kKru.jpg)

This is the expected output from the script:

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VQhh.jpg)

Comment: Have you seen this question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50467045/1256347